# Populating RITM Variables from a REST Call

Tags: rest, servicenow

I'm in the process of learning scripted REST API's. I have one that creates a REQ and RITM when the user does a POST. I'm having trouble populating variables from the rest post to the RITM. Below is my current code. Response is the RITM, Requester, and short description. I'm open to all suggestions, like I said I'm learning this on the fly, so if there is any glaring problems, I'm all ears. Thanks!

```
(function process(/*RESTAPIRequest*/ request, /*RESTAPIResponse*/ response) {

    var cartId = GlideGuid.generate(null);
    var cart = new Cart(cartId);
    var item = cart.addItem('25409830135aa20099fc7e776144b0a0'); 
    var rc = cart.placeOrder();
    var req = request.getHeader('ContactEmployeeId');
    var sdesc = request.getHeader('ShortDescription');
    //return rc.number;
    //gs.addInfoMessage(rc.number);
    var num = rc.sys_id;  //get sys ID of newly created request
    var rnum = 0;

    //using the request number, query the RITM table for related RITM
    var u = new GlideRecord('sc_req_item');
    u.addEncodedQuery('request='+num);
    u.query();
    while ( u.next() )
    {
        rnum = u.number;    
    }

    response.setBody({
        Requested_Item: rnum,
        u_requester: req,
        short_description: sdesc
    });

    response.setContentType('application/json');

})(request, response);
```

Comment: how does your request body looks like, please provide a sample of your request payload

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setVariable(ritm, variableName, value)` method such as this.

```
var cartId = GlideGuid.generate(null);
var cart = new Cart(cartId);
var item = cart.addItem('25409830135aa20099fc7e776144b0a0');

// add your variables here to the item variable in your cart object
cart.setVariable(item, "comments", message);
cart.setVariable(item, "my_var_1", value1);
cart.setVariable(item, "my_var_2", value2);

// submit order
var rc = cart.placeOrder();
```